# Limiting values for logistic function

Tags: limits

Given the logistic function (map)

$x_{n+1} = r\cdot{xn}\cdot (1 - {xn})$and an initial value  $x_{0} = 0.4$

When r = 0.5,

i worked out $x_{1}=0.12$ and $x_{2}=0.0528$

How do i work out the limiting value of ${xn}$ as n →∞?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you by any chance have $x_n$ instead of $xn$?

Answer (score 1):

What you do is to find a fixed point $f(x) = x$.  Then for each fixed point $x^*$, you find $f'(x^*)$.  If the derivative is less than $1$ in absolute value, it is a stable fixed point.  So quite likely it will converge to one of those stable fixed points.  I think when $r=0.5$, this is very straightforward to compute, and then given the numerical data you have acquired so far, I think you will be able to use standard tools like the mean value theorem to rigorously show it converges to the single stable fixed point.